# Auto: enable automotic update of links Ms-Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, updates, dde

How do I enable automatic updates of links for all users, even on other PCs?

I have more than 20 excel sheets that are all linked and need to update.

The problem is that sometimes users forget to click *enable automatic update of links*. How do I get this to be automatic on all PCs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/930479) method 4:

Method 4:

> Enable the automatic update for data connections or workbook links in
>   the Trust Center To enable the automatic update for data connections
>   or workbook links in the External Content section of the Trust Center,
>   follow these steps:
>
> ```
> Click the Microsoft Office Button, and then click Excel Options.
> Click Trust Center.
> Click Trust Center Settings.
> Click External Content.
> Click to select the following options, as appropriate for your situation:
>     Prompt user about Data Connections
>     Prompt user on automatic update for Workbook Links
> Click OK to close the Trust Center dialog box.
> Click OK to close the Excel Options dialog box.
> ```

You cannot and **should not** have objects or processes managed by the **trust center** automatically do *anything*. This is setting a bad precedent. Instead, you should set the workbooks to **prompt the users** to update every time they open the workbook. If the users are prompted, they will be reminded to update the links.

Additionally, you can take a look at [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/826921)

Comment: i read that each user have to enable from the option, so thanks for your help